# Only close mobile navigation if link has class

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I'm fairly new to jQuery and I'm trying to make my mobile menu (which opens through a menu button) to scroll to the section and close once a link has been pressed. 
The issue I'm having is that all my links are still slidetoggling the menu.

I only want links with the class "menu_links" to slidetoggle the menu.

(The css display section is to ensure the page is in mobile mode before toggling the menu and I'm not having and problems with it)

Please could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong and the better way to do so? Any help would be hugely appreciated!

```
//Smooth scrolling
$(document).ready (function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 1000);

          //Issues area
          if ($("a").hasClass("menu_links")) {
            if ($(".menuButton").css("display") == "block" ){
              $( ".menu" ).slideToggle( "medium" );
            }
          }
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: explain which line of code is going to be wrong???? I couldn't see any wrong code, but providing a fiddle would be better....

Comment: I've just marked the line I suspect to be wrong //Issues area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed line:

```
if ($("a").hasClass("menu_links")) {
```

to

```
if ($(this).hasClass('menu_links')) {
```